# Banned from asking questions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Sorry to bother you. I've seen this question answered elsewhere on the site but don't quite understand the ban. I've been banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow, potentially because of a single -1 on one question. I've never had any downvoted questions before.

I'm committed to be compliant with the Stack Exchange rules.

Please politely explain, bearing in mind I'm new around here.

Why has this been locked? This question is unique because: I haven't done anything wrong that I know of?

Comment: Any deleted questions?

Comment: Not that I'm aware, @Oded...

Comment: If you're sure you've never asked more questions than the 4 visible ones, are you using a shared computer perhaps? Or are you primarily using the site from a network with more SO users?

Comment: Private home computer, @Bart. I'm the only programmer in the household. Have posted more questions on other SE sites.

Comment: Okay, that won't be part of the problem then. The thing is that it's very unlikely you have been post-banned for a single downvoted question and another closed one.

Comment: @Bart I've gotten the (exceedingly unscientific) feeling that the team has been tightening up the requirements, but if the visible history is representative this seems a little excessive.

Comment: Can you sort it, @Bart? Can't imagine why.

Comment: @dmckee I have entirely different feelings, but we'll have to wait for a confirmation on those...

Comment: @MuckyDucky No, I can't. I'm a regular user. And even moderators can't really do anything about it. It's an automatic ban. You should improve your standing by positively contributing in ways still possible to you. Then the system might automatically lift your ban. If there are no skeletons in your closet, this should not take too much work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a reasonably new user and still finding my way around. If something is wrong somewhere, I'd appreciate it if it could be pointed out to me.

Comment: There are probably deleted questions. They don't show up on your profile, unless the user doing the looking is a mod.

Comment: @MuckyDucky A moderator might provide some more insights. But ultimately the answer is going to be "improve your contributions".

Comment: @MuckyDucky: users often ask about these on Meta Stack Overflow but forget that they have one or more downvoted deleted questions. Are you absolutely sure you have never asked any questions besides those four?

Comment: @MuckyDucky Shog9 reports that you are not currently q-banned. Try it again.

Comment: Not absolutely, @DavidRobinson - but there are none that spring to mind. I would contribute more but I'm new to the general programming background, so once I gain a bit more experience - I will be sure to give some back.

Comment: @dmckee Oh, so I'm not. When I tried to ask a question it took me to a plain page that said 'Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account' and it had a Goo.gl link to a page with explanations. Thanks for your help all! :) For the record, it took me here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998

Comment: You do have two closed and deleted questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673831/is-this-php-login-script-safe and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659729/easiest-way-to-prevent-php-mysql-injections . They were duplicates of others, but I'm not quite sure why Bill deleted them.

Comment: @MuckyDucky It seems you've recently received an upvote. That might have helped, but means you are also balancing on the edge. Make sure to ask good on-topic questions. Re-read the FAQ if you must. Good luck.

Comment: The q-ban can go from off- to -on or vice versa on the weight of a single vote, so it is possible that you were banned got a vote and no longer are. In that case you are still very close to the edge. My advice: ask *good* questions.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for pointing this out. Sometimes other questions don't make sense to me because I'm a beginner, and sometimes they just need rephrasing.

Comment: It happened again. :(

Answer (score -4):

It seems too harsh to ban you, but I've noticed that 3 of your 4 questions on StackOverflow are off-topic (imho). You should read the [StackOverflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), as well as the FAQs for other Stack sites you ask questions on.

Comment: Ah, I see. Can this be lifted?

Comment: Not by me. I don't think you should've been banned in the first place.

Comment: Hm, what? Only one of MuckyDucky's four visible questions is closed. The question ban is automatic and it wouldn't kick in for just one closed question. It would also not kick in for off topic questions that haven't been closed - it's smart, but not _that_ smart. _If_ there are no deleted questions, then the ban is strange, but if there are, then it might be perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Yannis I guess GregS meant "Only one out of four is closed, but be careful about your other ones". A statement I have to agree with. They are all not particularly strongly on-topic. I don't think he meant to imply that the filter took them into account.

Comment: @Bart: Correct, I should've have said that IMO 3 of the 4 are off-topic. That two of those are not closed is obvious.

Comment: Yep. I'm 14, so this is all one big learning curve for me, but as my experience grows I will take your comments into account.

Comment: @MuckyDucky: Stick with it, visit some of the other StackExchange sites to see what they're about.

Comment: I see what you mean now, makes much more sense than what I initially thought you were saying - downvote reversed. /cc: @Bart